# inconsistent results when timing a process

Tags: java, performance, timing

I'm trying to time the performance of my program by using `System.currentTimeMillis()` (or alternatively `System.nanoTime()`) and I've noticed that every time I run it - it gives a different result for time it took to finish the task.

Even the straightforward test:

```
long totalTime;
long startTime;
long endTime;
startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 1000000000; j++)
    {
    }
}
endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
totalTime = endTime-startTime;
System.out.println("Time: " + totalTime);
```

produces all sorts of different outputs, from 0 to 200. Can anyone say what I'm doing wrong or suggest an alternative solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The loop doesn't do anything, so you are timing how long it takes to detect the loop is pointless.

Timing the loops more accurately won't help, you need to do something slightly useful to get repeatable results.

I suggest you try `-server` if you are running on 32-bit windows.

A billion billion clock cycles takes about 10 years so its not really iterating that many times.

Comment: +1 For the calculation, an approximation of ten years won't be that bad. I calculated it at 13 years for a 2.4GHz CPU, singled threaded.

Comment: +1  I think Peter is understating things dramatically.  I've done a bit of benchmarking recently, and the JVM now has a just-in-time optimizer that will quickly spot which elements of the array you will check and fill those in __only__.  I suspect it's in cahoots with any random number generator you might try and use, too.  I also think it knows whether or not you are looking at the screen.  Good luck trying to trick it into doing some actual work.

Comment: Well originally I am doing stuff, I'm implementing three different greedy algorithms (first fit, next fit and best fit) and timing their performance. The problem is that sometimes best fit performs faster than both other ones, and sometimes the first fit does that and it doesn't make any sence (though the code for those algorithms seems correct).

Comment: You need to place each loop in a separate method, ignore the warm up time, and make sure you run the benchmark for at least 2 seconds.

Comment: If you must roll your own benchmarking -- which isn't always a great idea -- then run the method _without timing it_ for a few seconds, and _only then_ do timing.  You have to give the JIT time to optimize.

Comment: So it's not the first but the second run time that counts, did I understand that correctly? 
Also thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly the expected behavior -- it's supposed to get faster as you rerun the timing.  As you rerun a method many times, the JIT devotes more effort to compiling it to native code and optimizing it; I would expect that after running this code for long enough, the JIT would eliminate the loop entirely, since it doesn't actually do anything.

The best and simplest way to get precise benchmarks on Java code is to use a tool like [Caliper](http://caliper.googlecode.com) that "warms up" the JIT to encourage it to optimize your code fully.